# add git submodule as GWT dependency

Tags: java, git, gradle, gwt, dependencies

I have a java gradle project which is using a git submodule (api) as dependency.

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':api')
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':game', ':api'
```

This works on desktop fine! Now I want to translate my java code with gwt to JavaScript. But gwt gives me an error for every file from the api:

> did you forget to inherit a required module?

Is it right that I have to inherit these files? And how is it possible to inherit the complete api from git/gradle?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update the module descriptor! GWT does not know where to find the sources.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
What did you mean? In the gwt.xml? Do you have a link or something?